# Difference between 虫取り and 虫取りをする?

Tags: verbs

I'm a beginner, so I'm sorry if this is obvious: I was just reading a text which said

> 虫取りをしました

which, according to google, means "I took insects", which confused me at first because 取り is already a verb, isn't it? What would it mean if instead of that, the text had said

> 虫取りました

what role does the 取り verb play in the sentence if する is the main verb in the original?

Comment: Welcome to Japanese Stack Exchange. 虫取り is used as a noun in this case.

Comment: ohh ok I didn't know that, but I thought it might be that. Is there any difference in meaning though?

Comment: `虫取りました` is not correct. 「虫**を**取りました」 would be fine, though.

Comment: being fine and being correct are different though. A japanese would say 虫を捕まえる. Japanese isn't a constructed language, despite what the linguists says. There is what Japanese people say and then there is what is correct...Which do you think is more correct? What people say in everyday language, or what the scholors say is linguistically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find "虫取{むしと}る" (and so "虫取{むしと}ります") in any dictionary.

"虫{むし}取{と}り" is a noun, composed of "虫{むし}" which means insect, and the nominalization of "取{と}る" which generally means "to take", but in this case can be interpreted as "to catch".
"取{と}る" is nominalized by taking its stem, ie. turning its る to a り.

So in the end, "虫取り" is a compound noun that means "catching insects", and can be turned into a verb when used along with "する"; therefore "虫取りをする" means "to catch insects", or more literally, "to do insect catching".

Comment: Thanks! I've been loking online on how to nominalize verbs but only came across adding こと or の. Can you do this for any verb? Do you have maybe a link with this info? I'd like to understand it

Comment: Yeah, there are other ways to nominalize a verb. こと and の are used in many grammar structures. They're simply appended after the verb in plain form, so 取る would simply become 取ること or 取るの. As for stem nominalization, I couldn't find any decent source except for this question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59902/18582 (but no good answer); basically all you need to know is that the stem of a verb is a noun (but only from a grammar standpoing; it's very rarely directly used as a noun).

Comment: @SantiagoBosch See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32299/5010

Comment: いい参考ですね、ありがとう！私がリンクしたQAは余り役に立ちませんえ。。。

Comment: @naruto ありがとうございます！